# How to bind to a base type and a protocol in Xamarin.iOS

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin

I'm trying to build a xamarin app that utilizes the Cordova library. I've been working on my own binding for the components of the library I need, and so far, it has been working well.

Today I ran into an interesting problem though. I was trying to override the `webView: shouldStartLoadWithRequest:` method on the `CDVViewContainer` [available here](https://github.com/apache/cordova-ios/blob/master/CordovaLib/Classes/CDVViewController.h).

I've looked at the [Xamarin Binding Guide](http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/ios/application_fundamentals/delegates,_protocols,_and_events#3.protocols), and the Xamarin [Advanced Binding guide](http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/binding_objective-c_libraries/binding_types_reference_guide). Both of these note that Protocols are Analogous to interfaces, and as is shown in the Advanced binding guide

```
@interface UITextField : UIControl <UITextInput> {

}
```

would translate into

```
[BaseType (typeof (UIControl))]
interface UITextField : UITextInput {
}
```

Based on this, I translated

```
@interface CDVViewController : UIViewController <UIWebViewDelegate, CDVScreenOrientationDelegate>{

}
```

into

```
[BaseType (typeof (UIViewController))]
interface CDVViewController : UIWebViewDelegate {

}
```

But when I attempt to make my binding library, I get

```
Cordova.cs(26,39): error CS0527L Type `MonoTouch.UIKit.UIWebViewDelegate' in interface list is not an interface.
```

I checked the Apple Specifications, and [this is in fact a Protocol](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html). Can anyone help me figure out what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a limitation on the tool.  You can only use that syntax to adopt protocols when you include your own definition for it.   It does not work when adopting protocols that have been defined in an external definition.

Comment: This is unfortunate, as when I'm trying to do a native binding for phonegap, and in many of the classes, they inherit form a base class, and implement several protocols. The best way I've seen to get around this so far is to add all of the methods from the protocols to my binding class definition.

Comment: If I attempt to extend the class above, it apparently causes a segmentation fault (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15693762/monotouch-application-exits-unexpectedly-code-0-code-1-segmatation-fault-11). It appears that when you extend the class, calling the base method just calls the original method again, which calls the base method... Repeat until segmentation fault.

Comment: Maybe I'm not fully understanding the answer. Are you saying this only works if you are adopting a custom protocol and therefore are including the definition of the protocol in the same api definition? I'm adopting UIGestureRecognizerDelegate and I'm getting the same error, but I copied the binding from the assembly into the my binding class and it still doesn't resolve the error.